# Unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts c# and php

Tags: c#, php, mysql

i can connect to mysql with this config in PHP

PHP Code

```
$link = mysqli_connect("192.168.0.19", "mantaghe3", "Coq2Hoh1", "wf_mantaghe3",3308);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
else
{
    printf("connected!");
}
```

say :connected!

**But**

i can not connect to mysql with same config in C#

C# Code

```
try
{
    string conStr = "server=192.168.0.19;port=3308;database=wf_mantaghe3;uid=mantaghe3;pwd=Coq2Hoh1;charset=utf8;";
    conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
    conn.Open();
}
catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    return;
}
```

in windows 7(my system) C# connect to mysql but in windows server 2008 say error?!!

say error :Unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts

why?? please help me!

Comment: I have never used C# before, but reading the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it looks like you are using an incorrect syntax. I may be wrong, though. Try something like, `server=tcp:192.168.0.19,3308`.

Comment: no `server=tcp:192.168.0.19,3308` is for Data Source.this syntax for connection string is right

Comment: Your example code will either not run or not even compile. Is it `conStr` or `myConnectionString`? Please provide the shortest compilable example that exhibits the error behaviour.

Comment: C# code compiled and run and in line `conn.Open();` throw exception `Unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts`

Comment: I guess it must be a typo, but just in case: the connection string is in `conStr`, but then conn uses `myConnectionString`

Comment: @Alvaro Montoro yes yes ,sorry i am so stupid :{

Comment: Nobody is stupid, that's a mistake that everybody makes. Now the question: is that a typo when writing the question? or is it in your code and the cause of the error?

Comment: unfortunately it was in my code :(